# Trouble printing variables from other files

Tags: python, python-2.7

#### Description

I have a script → `report_creator.py` which will need some variables from another python script → `extracted_data.py`.
The number of variables from `extracted_data.py` will always be based on the system it extracts data from (if the system has 1 server, we will have 1 variable, if the system has 2 servers, we will have 2 variables and so on). You can never know the exact number of variables the `extracted_data.py` will have.

Let's say we have extracted data from a system with 2 servers and the `extracted_data.py` file looks something like:

```
parameterx_server1 = "value"
parameterx_server2 = "another value"
```

**What I have:** → `report_creator.py`:

```
import os
import extracted_data

#Extract all variables names starting with parameterx from extracted_data.py and store them into a list

variables = os.popen("""cat extracted_data.py | grep '^parameterx_*' | awk '{print $1}'""").read().strip()
variables = variables.split("\n")

#After the execution of the command, the list looks like this:
# variables = ['parameterx_server1', 'parameterx_server2']
```

#### Problem

The script now has a list containing all the `parameterx` variables from `extracted_data.py`:

```
variables = ['parameterx_server1', 'parameterx_server2']
```

The only thing remaining is to get the corresponding value of each variable from the variables list from the `extracted_data.py`, something like:

```
print extracted_data.parameterx_server1
```

I tried something like:

```
for variable in variables:
    print extracted_data.variable
```

But for some reason I get an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'variable'`.

Comment: Use  `print getattr(extracted_data, variable)` instead to get attrbutes whose name is in a string

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me.  You might look into the [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) module instead of trying to parse Python files.

Comment: or better yet, use `dir(extracted_data)` to list the attributes instead of shelling out. or loop over `for k, v in vars(extracted_data).items():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the variables and their value defined in the `extracted_data.py` file like this:

```
import extracted_data

extract_vars = {name: getattr(extracted_data, name)
                    for name in dir(extracted_data) if not name.startswith('_')}
print(extract_vars)  # -> {'parameterx_server2': 'another value', 'parameterx_server1': 'value'}
```

As shown, afterwards `extract_vars` is a dictionary containing both the variable names *and* associated values.